# unable to get value from dojo textbox after button onclick

Tags: vb.net, dojo

I am using the dojox/mobile/button on a view to get input values which I want to then submit to a database table. I am unable to get the values as I expect to and also would like to know if anyone has some links or sample code for .Net web application that uses similar dojo tools or even the form tools.

```
<input type="text" id="clientName" dojoType="dojox.mobile.TextBox" value="" 
required="true">

<input type="submit" onclick="insertData();" style="width: 140px;" 
    class="mblBlueButton" dojoType="dojox.mobile.Button" value="Submit">
```

My insertData function as follows:

```
 function insertData() { 
                    var clientProj = dojox.byId("clientName").value; 
                    var clientKey = dojox.byId("clientKey").value; 
                    alert("NEW CLIENT DATA ACCEPTED - " + clientProj); 

                }
```

I tested it by putting an alert in the first line of the function and that worked but it seems it may be failing because the textbox value is null.

EDIT:

For now I removed the mobile textboxes and ended using dijit/form/textbox and works fine. Would still appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a DOM value you just have to use dojo.byId, or since its a widget, you should be able to get it with just the id value...  so clientName.value within your javascript.

If you need to access widget specific features you would use dijit.registry.byId.

Comment: thanks for your response. I did try that and not sure why it did not work. will keep playing around with it. Do you have suggestions on how to access the clientName.value from the code behind file aspx.vb. This is a .Net application.